# VirtualBox VMs crash rapidly

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've used VirtualBox on a number of machines (including some really old creaky ones) over the years with great success.  However, I have a new computer where it doesn't work!  64-bit AMD machine with Windows 10 x64 (up to date on patches).  VirtualBox works fine in the control panels, but whenever I open a VM, that VM hard freezes almost exactly 5 seconds after startup.  I've tried disc images that work fine on other machines.  Most recently FreeDOS 1.2 and openSuSE LEAP.  What kind of settings should I look for that might need adjustment on the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, figured it out already.  Somehow Hyper-V got enabled on that machine and rather than alerting in some fashion, VirtualBox VMs instead crash seconds after startup.  Disabled Hyper-V in Program Features and I'm all good again!